# Fill NA with previous value based on multiple column

Tags: r, dplyr

Im new with R.

Currently i'm working with dplyr package for manipulation data.
But i'm stuck when want to do some calculation as below:

```
library(dplyr)
w18 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
w19 <- c(10,10,NA,NA,NA)
temp_df <- data.frame(w18,w19)
```

I expect NA will replaced with value from `w19 <- ifelse(is.na(w19), lag(w19)+ lag(w18) else w19`

how ever when im tried with my code as below:

```
w19_function <- function(temp_df) {
isna <- is.na(temp_df)
lag_w19 <- tail(temp_df[!isna],1)
loc <- length(w18[!is.na(w18),])
temp_df[isna] <- lag_w19+ temp_df[loc,'w18']
return(temp_df)
}
w19_function(temp_df)
```

i expect result like this one :

```
w18,w19
1,10
2,10
3,12
4,15
5,19
```

but the code giving result :

```
w18,w19
1,10
2,10
3,12
4,12
5,12
```

what thing I should to add? please help me for solving this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work as well for you:

```
library(tidyverse)
w18 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
w19 <- c(10,10,NA,NA,NA)
temp_df <- data.frame(w18,w19)
temp_df

temp_df %>%
  mutate(step = cumsum(if_else(is.na(w19), lag(w18), 0))) %>%
  fill(w19) %>%
  mutate(w19 = w19 + step) %>%
  select( -step)

# w18 w19
# 1   1  10
# 2   2  10
# 3   3  12
# 4   4  15
# 5   5  19
```

(modified: with repeats)

```
temp_df %>%
  mutate(grp = cumsum(if_else(!is.na(w19) & is.na(lag(w19)), 1, 0))) %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  mutate(step = cumsum(if_else(is.na(w19), lag(w18), 0))) %>%
  fill(w19) %>%
  mutate(w19 = w19 + step) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select( -step, -grp)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to capture values which were changed on the fly.

Sometimes a traditional `for` loop can be helpful

```
for (i in seq_len(nrow(temp_df))) {
   if(is.na(temp_df$w19[i])) {
     temp_df$w19[i] <- temp_df$w18[i-1] + temp_df$w19[i-1]
   }
}

temp_df
#  w18 w19
#1   1  10
#2   2  10
#3   3  12
#4   4  15
#5   5  19
```

Comment: Thanks, man..
I think i can go on with your code on for my work. Thanks a lot, really appreciate